# Can anyone help me sort out my xpaths? I'm looking for specific information from a forum and I don't know why I keep getting errors

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

Can aynone help me with my selectors: I want to get the username and post content only from a forum site. When i use `Content = response.xpath('//html//p//text()').getall()` i get all text from the site (i know if there are any forum posts) and when i try to make it more specific `Content = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(id="post_message"//text()').getall()` I get error messages and an empty file.

The only thing i can think is that my selectors are wrong, or that I need to be logged in. i have no idea about a 'logged in' webscraper. I have included my code with some inspection examples.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

Websites = ["https://www.fodors.com/community/trending.php"]

class spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"
    start_urls = Websites
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
    D = {}
    links = []
#   links = [item for sublist in links for item in sublist]
    def start_requests(self):
        for W in self.start_urls:
            self.D[W] = []
            yield scrapy.Request(W, callback = self.ParseLinks)

    def ParseLinks(self, response):
        Link = response.xpath(".//a//@href").extract()
        self.links.append(Link)
        for W in self.D:
            self.D[W] = Link
    #       self.links = [item for sublist in self.links for item in sublist]
            for List in self.links:
                for L in List:
                    yield response.follow(L, callback=self.ParseContent)



    def ParseContent(self, response):
    #   Content = response.xpath('//html//p//text()').extract()
    #   Content = response.xpath('//html//p//text()').get().extract()
    #   Content = ''.join(sel.select("//body//text()").extract()).strip()
    #   Content = response.xpath('//html//p[contains(@class,"heading")]//text()').extract()
    #   Content = response.xpath('//body/node()/text()').extract_first() 
    #   Content = response.xpath('//html//p//text()').getall()
    #   Content = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id="post_message")]/text()').extract()
        User = response.xpath('//html//div/a[contains(@class="bigusername")]/text()').get()
        Content = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(id="post_message"//text()').getall()
        FinalText = yield {User: Content}
    #   print(Content)
        print(FinalText)

#full xpath copy and paste for each
#/html/body/div[4]/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a
#/html/body/div[4]/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]

#element <a rel="nofollow" class="bigusername" href="/community/profile/NAME/">NAME</a>
#text <div id="post_message_NUMBER">                        
#                       text text text
#                   </div>

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(spider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Learn (1) the difference between `//` and `/` in XPath and (2) how to write a proper title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath has a wrong syntax. Use this instead:

```
Content = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(id,"post_message")]//text()').getall()
```

Maybe add an `@` before the `id` if it's an attribute.

Comment: thanks, i'm sorry, i made some typos with my question. I changed it to `User = response.xpath('//html//div/a[contains(@class="bigusername")]//text()').getall()
  Content = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id="post_message")]//text()').getall()` but i get the error 'Invalid number of arguments in //html//div/a[contains(@class="bigusername")]//text()`

Comment: You made the same mistake again. Look closely at my answer and recognize that `contains()` has two arguments and not one comparison: it's `contains(@id,"post_message")` and **not** `contains(@id="post_message")`, in both occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

incase it helps someone else, here is my final xpath

`XS = response.xpath('//html//div[contains(@id, "post_message")]')
User = XS.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "community/profile")]//text()').getall()
Content = XS.xpath('//b//text()').getall()`